# "Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate" while installing build-essential

Tags: apt, dependencies

I have tried following command and it is showing me error:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Results:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: cannot add the sources list as it ix saying that u need more than 10 reputation to post more than 2 links

Comment: Add the links then select the whole thing a press Ctrl + K, so it gets spaced, like the one above.

Comment: Or post the link as a comment and somebody with enough reputation can edit your post

Comment: Since the author of this post has not responded since, I'm going to close this question. Rummy Khan: If you can provide the information requested by Braiam (you now have over 10 reputation) please *edit* the information in and add a comment letting me know (make sure you include `@Seth` in the comment to make sure I get it) and I'll see about getting this question reopened.